# solving math equation for data loading problem

Tags: python, numpy, math

I'm having a dataframe df_N with n observations.  I'd want to write a code that would create new dataframe df_M with records from df_N. The number of observations in df_M ( ie m observations ) is several orders greater that the number of observations on df_N.
The number of observations on df_M can be represented in by the following formula.

> m = (n*(2^x)) + n^y + z

Note that the first part of the equation is the series n, n*2, n*4, n*8. ie n times 2^x

Note that all values are integers.

For example if n = 8 and m = 82
the values of the formula would be
82= (8*(2^3) + 8^2 + 2  = 8*8 + 16 + 2 = 64 + 16 + 2 = 82
values of x = 3 , y = 2 and z = 2

Also note that always  (n*(2^x)) >  n^y  > z . This constraint will restrict the number of solutions for the equation.

Is there a way of solving this equation on python and finding the values of x y and z, given n and m?

Once the value of x y and z are determined, I'd be able to write a code  to create additional records for each of the segment of the equation and combiming them to a single dataframe df_M

Comment: You said you have to create a new df_M.  Did you mean you are GIVEN df_M?  If each `n` produces 100 different `m`s, then clearly there is not going to be a single formula to map one to the other.  Otherwise, if x/y/z are constant, this is a simple linear mapping.

Comment: @TimRoberts, My lack of expression mathematical equation may have resulted in the confusion. Yes, m and n are given values and I'd need to determine x, y and z,  Also (n*(2^x)) > n^y > z. I've edited the formula to the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is to find the values of x, y, and z in the equation m = (n*(2^x)) + n*y + z, where the values of m and n are given.

To solve this problem, we can follow these steps:

Step 1: Divide m by n and store the quotient in the variable "quotient".

```
quotient = m // n
```

Step 2: Calculate the value of x using the bit_length() method of the quotient minus 1. This determines the highest power of 2 that divides the given value of m.

```
x = quotient.bit_length() - 1
```

Step 3: Subtract n*(2^x) from m to eliminate the first term in the equation.

```
m -= n * (2 ** x)
```

Step 4: Divide the updated value of m by n and store the quotient in the variable "y".

```
y = m // n
```

Step 5: Calculate the value of z by subtracting y*n from the updated value of m.

```
z = m - y * n
```

By following these steps, we can find the values of x, y, and z in the given equation m = (n*(2^x)) + n*y + z.

Remember to substitute the given values of m and n into the equation and then execute the code to obtain the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you also want to maximize `n*y` over `z`, `m` and `n` are positive and other numbers should be non-negative:

```
x = m.bit_length() - 1
m -= 2**x
y = m//n
z = m - y*n
```